# Client-side AOP options for GWT apps

Tags: java, gwt, aop

It would be nice to be able to define my own method interceptors (advice) and weave them in to my client-side GWT methods, and have GWT automagicallly compile them down into JavaScript with the rest of my app.

I checked out `gwt-ent`, but it doesn't look like there's been solid development on it since 2009 and there were quite a number of issues. I've also heard of `gwt-tiny-aop` but heard it was very limited.

Do I have any other options here? I know AOP requires dynamic bytecode generation, which in turn requires heavy reflection, and that GWT doesn't contain a lot of support (and seems to discourage) the practice of reflection, but I was wondering if there are any stable, well-known AOP libs out there for GWT. At least something that I could use for writing AOP Alliance-like interceptors:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void onIntercept(MethodInvocation mi) {
        // Do some stuff...

        // Let the method execute
        Object results = mi.proceed();

        // Analyze results...

        // Returns results
        return results;
}
```

Comment: why not use javascript (wrapped in JSNI) to simulate that behavior?

Comment: Something like [dotvoid](http://www.dotvoid.com/2005/06/aspect-oriented-programming-and-javascript/) perhaps? Not a bad idea...definitely a candidate, but still would prefer a Java solution if at all possible

Comment: To use AOP with GWT, you'd have to massage the source code before giving it to GWT, rather than massage bytecode.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasBroyer (+1) - can you please explain what you mean by "massage the source code" and perhaps provide a code example? Thanks again!

Comment: I mean create new source with the interceptors _merged_ into the original methods. You could then pass those enhanced sources to the GWT compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You could use GWT generators:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred#generators

Comment: @IAmYourFaja: This is the answer for all that involves or depends on the Reflexion API on GWT client code... believe me, there is no way to do it but with generators.